# React JS shortern attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I am working on **React Js** and I faced a problem that is I need to store a large amount of value/attributes. 
My code as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../Container/Company.css'
import { Container, Col, Form, Row, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap';
class AddCompany extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      CompanyName: '',
      CompanyReg: '',
      CompanyAddr1: '',
      CompanyAddr2: '',
      CompanyAddr3: '',
      City: '',
      State: '',
      PostCode: '',
      Phone: '',
      Fax: '',
      ContactPerson: '',
      Email: '',
      DealerName: '',
      Phone2: '',
      Country: '',
      Remark: '',
      DealerCode: '',
      SerialNo: '',
      IsActive: '',
    }
  }
  AddCompany = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:57025/api//companyedit/', {
      CompanyName: this.state.CompanyName,
      CompanyReg: this.state.CompanyReg,
      CompanyAddr1: this.state.CompanyAddr1,
      CompanyAddr2: this.state.CompanyAddr2,
      CompanyAddr3: this.state.CompanyAddr3,
      City: this.state.City,
      PostCode: this.state.PostCode,
      Phone: this.state.Phone,
      Fax: this.state.Fax,
      ContactPerson: this.state.ContactPerson,
      Email: this.state.Email,
      DealerName: this.state.DealerName,
      Phone2: this.state.Phone2,
      Country: this.state.Country,
      Remark: this.state.Remark,
      DealerCode: this.state.DealerCode,
      SerialNo: this.state.SerialNo,
      IsActive: this.state.IsActive})
      .then(json => {
        if (json.data.Status === 'Success') {
          console.log(json.data.Status);
          alert("Data Save Successfully");
          this.props.history.push('/CompanyList')
        }
        else {
          alert('Data not Saved');
          debugger;
          this.props.history.push('/CompanyList')
        }
      })
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container className="App">
        <h4 className="PageHeading">Enter Company Informations</h4>
        <Form className="form">
          <Col>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Label for="CompanyName" sm={2}>CompanyName</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" CompanyName="CompanyName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.CompanyName} placeholder="Enter Name" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="CompanyReg" sm={2}>CompanyReg</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" CompanyReg="CompanyReg" onChange={this.handleChange.CompanyReg} value={this.state.CompanyReg} placeholder="Enter Reg" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="CompanyAddr1" sm={2}>CompanyAddr1</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" CompanyAddr1="CompanyAddr1" onChange={this.handleChange.CompanyAddr1} value={this.state.CompanyAddr1} placeholder="Enter Address Line 1" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="CompanyAddr2" sm={2}>CompanyAddr2</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" CompanyReg="CompanyAddr2" onChange={this.handleChange.CompanyAddr2} value={this.state.CompanyAddr2} placeholder="Enter Address Line 2" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="CompanyAddr3" sm={2}>CompanyAddr3</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" CompanyAddr3="CompanyAddr3" onChange={this.handleChange.CompanyAddr3} value={this.state.CompanyAddr3} placeholder="Enter Address Line 3" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="City" sm={2}>City</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" City="City" onChange={this.handleChange.City} value={this.state.City} placeholder="Enter City" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="State" sm={2}>State</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" State="State" onChange={this.handleChange.State} value={this.state.State} placeholder="Enter State" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="PostCode" sm={2}>PostCode</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" PostCode="PostCode" onChange={this.handleChange.PostCode} value={this.state.PostCode} placeholder="Enter PostCode" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Phone" sm={2}>Phone</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" Phone="Phone" onChange={this.handleChange.Phone} value={this.state.Phone} placeholder="Enter Phone" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Fax" sm={2}>Fax</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" Fax="Fax" onChange={this.handleChange.Fax} value={this.state.Fax} placeholder="Enter Fax" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="ContactPerson" sm={2}>ContactPerson</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" ContactPerson="ContactPerson" onChange={this.handleChange.ContactPerson} value={this.state.ContactPerson} placeholder="Enter ContactPerson" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Email" sm={2}>Email</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" Email="Email" onChange={this.handleChange.Email} value={this.state.Email} placeholder="Enter Email" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="DealerName" sm={2}>DealerName</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" DealerName="DealerName" onChange={this.handleChange.DealerName} value={this.state.DealerName} placeholder="Enter DealerName" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Phone2" sm={2}>Phone2</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" Phone2="Phone2" onChange={this.handleChange.Phone2} value={this.state.Phone2} placeholder="Enter Second Phone Number" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Country" sm={2}>Country</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" Country="Country" onChange={this.handleChange.Country} value={this.state.Cpuntry} placeholder="Enter Country" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Remark" sm={2}>Remark</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" Remark="Remark" onChange={this.handleChange.Remark} value={this.state.Remark} placeholder="Enter Remark" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="DealerCode" sm={2}>DealerCode</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" PostCode="DealerCode" onChange={this.handleChange.DealerCode} value={this.state.DealerCode} placeholder="Enter DealerCode" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="SerialNo" sm={2}>SerialNo</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" SerialNo="SerialNo" onChange={this.handleChange.SerialNo} value={this.state.SerialNo} placeholder="Enter SerialNo" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="IsActive" sm={2}>IsActive</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input type="text" IsActive="IsActive" onChange={this.handleChange.IsActive} value={this.state.IsActive} placeholder="Enter Y or N" />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col sm={5}>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={1}>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.Addstudent} className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={1}>
                <Button color="danger">Cancel</Button>{' '}
              </Col>
              <Col sm={5}>
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }

}

export default AddCompany;
```

I was trying to **AddCompany** by storing information that user key in and passing this info to my backend api. It seems that this is a clumsy way to do this.

Is there anyway to shorten all my attributes write form from api fetching, storing or declaration etc? Or anybody had a greater idea for writing this?

Comment: For one, you can simply send `this.state` via axios.

Comment: You can use the spread operator on `this.state` if you want to send everything in the object.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG I am new to React so I would like to ask you for demonstration how to do it in your way? Much appreciated!

Comment: Nothing really to do with react; you're creating a copy but that's not necessary at all: `axios.post('http://localhost:57025/api//companyedit/', this.state).then(...` Axios simply reads that data, so passing state directly is perfectly safe.

Comment: Hi @Jacob [https://www.techiediaries.com/react-spread-operator-props-setstate/] Am I looking for the correct link?

Comment: You have `CompanyName="CompanyName"`, which is supposed to be `id="CompanyName"`. There's also no `this.handleChange.CompanyName`, you need to make that a parameter and use currying. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-merkle-gscvm (replaced the first three fields, giving one line per field).

Comment: @ChrisG I take your sandbox as references and now it is working well so far. Thanks for your code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach will be storing all the attributes in separate file.
For eg. data.js

```
export const attributes = {
      CompanyName: '',
      CompanyReg: '',
      CompanyAddr1: '',
      CompanyAddr2: '',
      CompanyAddr3: '',
      City: '',
      State: '',
      PostCode: '',
      Phone: '',
      Fax: '',
      ContactPerson: '',
      Email: '',
      DealerName: '',
      Phone2: '',
      Country: '',
      Remark: '',
      DealerCode: '',
      SerialNo: '',
      IsActive: '',
}
```

and import that object in current page like

```
import { attributes } from './your_location';
```

Initialise state like:

```
constructor(){
 super();
 this.state = {...attributes}
}
```

On post request send like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:57025/api//companyedit/', {...this.state})
```

This will work fine and looks organised.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Pritiam that was quite a clear formatting for me. Thank you!

Comment: I think I am pretty sure I did the same thing :D

Comment: This answer does not address what to me is the most important issue: reduce the tons of duplicate code in the JSX. Sure, putting the attributes in a separate file is maybe more organized, but if they aren't needed elsewhere, too, this doesn't have any real benefit.

Comment: @ChrisG umm...
To reduce more redundancy of the JSX codes we can create another functional component which will return <FormGroup>. As state attributes name and Input, Label props are same so we can easily pass those state attribute  as props by creating a loop.

Comment: Ne need to explain this to *me*, but I just realized that OP isn't even asking about shortening everything though. So your answer is fine. I still feel the extreme redundancy in the JSX should be pointed out though.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG I had saw your sandbox demo. I will take the reference answer from both of you and Pritam. Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: @Pritam Actually both method from you and ChrisG worked. However according to  Pritam method's, I was able to reuse the attributes to my other pages. So actually both of your methods worked for me. Thank you so much  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
AddCompany = () => {
axios.post('http://localhost:57025/api//companyedit/', {
   ...this.state
},
...
...
```

This should solve it in case the Api's Request body has same key names.
Else you can create a mapper for the form's fields to the Api request body's fields. Like :

```
const myMapper = {
      'CompanyName': 'ApiCompanyName',
      ...
      ...
}
```

And run a loop to get the correct req body.

Comment: Again, why do `{ ...this.state }` when you can do `this.state`? There's no need to create a copy.

Comment: Yes. Just added in case you want to make some changes, so better create a ref.

Comment: I meant: `axios.post(url, this.state).then(...`